# From UI the value of MailingState field is in UpperCase, but when I query the data it shows in lowerCase

Tags: apex

While creating the records of contact, the `MailingState` field's value is given as "MN", and after saving the data it shows as "MN" in the standard salesforce UI.
However, when I query the data it shows "mn".

It is happening when the record is getting created from one specific user.

Any idea what can be wrong with the user?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post code ?

Comment: Hello, I have no custom code written here. I can send you the screenshots if you want.

Comment: I believe I should mention that we have "State and Country/Territory Picklists" enabled in our org. I have no idea as in why it is in lowercase when I query it.

Comment: can you please paste the query also.

Comment: select MailingState FROM Contact WHERE id='0032a00000V8v6JAAR'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of `State and Country/Territory Picklists`.Please check `Configure state and country/territory picklists` under `State and Country/Territory Picklists`.So, in query select `MailingStateCode` instead of `MailingState` like :

```
 SELECT MailingStateCode FROM Contact WHERE id='0032a00000V8v6JAAR'
```

Comment: I have checked that MailingStateCode='MN' and MailingState="mn" for this recod. I did not understand, when we create contact from any other user both the  MailingStateCode and MailingState is "MN", but why creating the record from a specific user will put MailingStateCode as 'MN' and MailingState as "mn". Is there anything to do with profile?

Comment: Maybe for old records value will be same (`MN`).

Comment: But now after enabling `State and Country/Territory Picklists` feature. You have to use `MailingStateCode`. As we will get value from picklist.

Comment: Thank you for explaning. Your explanation answers why I see different values in UI(MailingStateCode) and in dev console(MailingState). But I have one more unanswered question, that is why for a specific user we have different values for MailingStateCode and MailingState.

Comment: Could please mark this as resolved and create a new question.